# Runtime root partition resizing using GParted

Tags: arch-linux, partition

I'm running Arch Linux with Windows 7 dual booted. I've left a hefty chunk of my drive for windows, though I don't use it much anymore. I also need more space for my root partition.

So my plan is to wipe windows, increase the size of my root partition, and then create another partition left over for tertiary use.

I need to know if online resizing through GParted would allow me to increase my / partition size without any hiccups:

[image]

So if I wipe my windows partition and try to resize root, will I run into any trouble?

PS: I've done it once on a test machine, where I had a bunch of space after my partition (unlike the case below), but I did it on a whim since there weren't any consequences.

I need to know whether it may break my system.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: I don't know for sure whether it would work or not, but I would not advise trying it.   Reboot using the [gparted live ISO](http://gparted.org/) and perform the deletion of sda2, and the move + resize of sda3 while the system is offline.   Making a backup **before** any major file-system/partition manipulation is also recommended.

Comment: note also that gparted is capable of shrinking an NTFS partition, so if you wanted to keep a small windows partition, you could delete unwanted files from it, defrag it, and then shrink it with gparted before moving + resizing sda3.

Comment: Yes use a live OS. Your root partition is before the extended partition so should work fine. Because you are extending the root from the "front" all of the data will be copied (18GB) forward. If you run into issues with your boot just reinstall grub.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't done in Gparted

Boot into windows and install **MiniTool Partition Wizard** in this you can resize a partition

https://www.partitionwizard.com/help/resize-partition.html